# NSString : String extraction from a comma Separated NSString

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsstring

Below are two examples of strings separated by comma that I get back as results:

```
NSString *placeResult = @"111 Main Street, Cupertino, CA"
```

or sometimes the result contains the name of a place:

```
NSString *placeResult = @"Starbucks, 222 Main Street, Cupertino, CA"
```

What's the best way to check the strings above to see if it starts with a name or or a street address?

If it does start with a name (i.e. Starbucks in the 2nd example above"), I'd like to extract the name and store it into another variable.  Thus after extraction the string will be:

```
NSLog (@"%s", placeResult);
```

The log will print:

```
"222 Main Street, Cupertino, CA"
```

Another string will now store the @"Starbucks" in it:

```
NSLog (@"%s", placeName);
```

The log will print:

```
"Starbucks"
```

Important: I can't lose the comma separations after extraction.

Thank you!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Make use of `NSDataDetector` and `NSTextCheckingResult`:

```
NSDataDetector *detector = [NSDataDetector dataDetectorWithTypes:NSTextCheckingTypeAddress error:nil];
NSString *str = @"Starbucks, 222 Main Street, Cupertino, CA";
NSArray *matches = [detector matchesInString:str options:0 range:NSMakeRange(0, str.length)];
for (NSTextCheckingResult *match in matches) {
    if (match.resultType == NSTextCheckingTypeAddress) {
        NSDictionary *data = [match addressComponents];
        NSLog(@"address = %@, range: %@", data, NSStringFromRange(match.range));

        NSString *name = data[NSTextCheckingNameKey];
        if (!name && match.range.location > 0) {
            name = [str substringToIndex:match.range.location - 1];
            // "name" may now include a trailing comma and space - strip these as needed
        }
    }
}
```

This outputs:

> address = {
>       City = Cupertino;
>       State = CA;
>       Street = "222 Main Street";
>   }, range: {11, 30}

The odd thing is that the resulting dictionary of results does not contain a reference to the "Starbucks" portion. What you can do is check to see of the `addressComponents` contains  a value for the `NSTextCheckingNameKey`. If not, check the range of the match. If the match's range isn't the start of the string, then you can use that value to extract the name from the beginning of the string.

Comment: Very concise and clever approach.  I didn't know you can do NSTextCheckingTypeAddress.  Question:  If NSTextCheckingNameKey is blank, why do I need to check the range of the match?

Comment: Look at the example in my answer. The address doesn't contain the name "Starbucks". Since there is no value for `NSTextCheckingNameKey` you need to see if there really is a name at the start of the string. You can do this by looking at the match's range. If it's non-zero then you can assume the start of the string up to that match range is an overlooked name. But this all really depends on the strings you need to parse.

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm still confused.  I'm trying to pasre from Google places Autocomplete.  It returns the address in the format in the my question.  I just ran your code and you're right, there is no reference for "Starbucks".  Can you please elaborate on "see if there really is a name at the start of the string.   You can do this by looking at the match's range. If it's non-zero then you can assume the start of the string up to that match range is an overlooked name."  At this point i'm simply trying to parse (@"Starbucks, 222 Main Street, Cupertino, CA"); Clearly Starbucks is the first string.

Comment: Can you please explain this line: name = [str substringToIndex:match.range.location - 1];

Comment: What part don't you understand?

Comment: match.range.location-1.  I think range is from NSRange(location.length).  What does location-1. mean?

Comment: `match.range` represents the part of the string that contained the actual address. `match.range.location` is the start of the range. Subtracting 1 means to go to the previous character.

Answer (score 2):

To get an array of the things between commas, you could use:

```
NSArray *components = [placeResult componentsSeparatedByString:@","];
```

Possibly with a follow-up of:

```
NSMutableArray *trimmedComponents =
           [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:[components count]];

NSCharacterSet *whitespaceCharacterSet = [NSCharacterSet whitespaceCharacterSet];

for(NSString *component in components)
    [trimmedComponents addObject:
             [component stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:whitespaceCharacterSet]];
```

To remove any leading or trailing spaces from each individual component. You would reverse the transformation using e.g.

```
NSString *fullAddress = [trimmedComponents componentsJoinedByString:@", "];
```

So then the question is, given `NSString *firstComponent = [trimmedComponents objectAtIndex:0];`, how do you guess whether it is a name or a street address? If it's as simple as checking whether there's a number at the front that isn't zero then you can just do:

```
if([firstComponent integerValue])
{
    /* ... started with a non-zero number ... */

    NSString *trimmedAddress = [[trimmedComponents subArrayWithRange:
      NSMakeRange(1, [trimmedComponents count]-1)] componentsJoinedByString:", "];

    NSLog(@"trimmed address is: %@");
}
```

Though that conditional test would also have worked with `placeResult`, and you'll probably want to add validity checks to make sure you have at least two components before you start assuming you can make an array from the 2nd one onwards.